# Stores and ordered rank of products

Tags: nonparametric, dataset, ranking

I have data about popularity of some products in some stores. For each of the stores I have only a ordered rank of best-selling products in them. I need help how to find information about which products are popular only in certain stores versus products that are popular in all stores.